# How to filter alerts results in prometheus 2.11 /api/v1/alerts rest api call

Tags: rest, prometheus, alerts

I trying to do a rest api call to prometheus alerts (/api/v1/alerts) where I could filter by label.

I have tried querying the api as follows:

`/api/v1/query?query=ALERTS{host="11.11.11.11"}`

But i cannot get the alert annotations. So I tried with the following:

`/api/v1/alerts`

But I don't know if it is possible to filter the results.

Currently, I am doing this through Alert Manager but I want to get rid of it and get this information directly from Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter those currently via the alerts endpoint, so you'd have to do so client side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can now using query as a filter:

```
api/v2/alerts/groups?filter=namespace=demo-dev&filter=alertname=DemoServiceRandomSimpleGauge
```

In above namespace and altername are in labels, so anything in label can be filtered on.